# TYPO3 extbase: Simple readable GET parameters

Tags: typo3, extbase

GET and POST parameters in custom extbase controllers need to be prefixed with the plugin signature to be injected automatically:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Example\Controller;

class SearchController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    public function resultsAction($q = null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Search term `$q` is only filled automatically if it is passed as `?tx_example_search[q]=foo`.

Is there a way declare that the readable version `?q=foo` is also fine, and that this should be injected by extbase as well?

(I know that this breaks when multiple plugins on the same page use that parameter, but that's no problem here.)

(The parameter mapping seems already done when `ActionController::processRequest()` is called, so it must be done earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Extbase Plugin enhancer within the routing configuration.
See here: [TYPO3 Advanced routing configuration Docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#extbase-plugin-enhancer)

TYPO3 would then transform the EXTbase URLs into an readable version.

**Example:**

without the routeEnhancer: yourdomain.com/?tx_example_search[q]=foo

with the routeEnhancer: yourdomain.com/foo

Tipp: You have to define all GET Params otherwise TYPO3 will show the cHash Param.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP($var)` in order to retrieve parameters from global variables GET/POST.

Or also `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET($var)` or `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_POST($var)`.

Take care of security, those parameters are not sanitized !

If you really want to add the parameter to the action, you have to create an initializeAction() and set the parameter, something like this I guess :

```
public function initializeResultsAction() {
   $myVar = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('q');
   $this->request->setArgument('q', $myVar);
}
```

Comment: This is something I have to do manually in my action. Extbase does not inject them into the method parameters automatically. Also, extbase does not sanitize parameters either. You always have to quote/escape them.

Comment: Sure you have to done it manually but you have to because you want to do something that's not extbase standard.

Comment: For sanitize I would like to say use type hint in order to assure that the parameter is a string, an array, an int or a bool.